# Badge Oneboxer for Chat.SE

Tags: javascript, stackexchange, chat, userscript

This script makes it possible for badges to onebox in Chat.

[image]

---

The install requires Tamper/GreaseMonkey. Click [here](https://github.com/The-Quill/badge-oneboxer/raw/master/badge-oneboxer.user.js) to install,
and [it's on GitHub](https://github.com/The-Quill/badge-oneboxer) and [StackApps](https://stackapps.com/questions/6756/badge-oneboxer-for-chat)!

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name Badge Oneboxer
// @description Converts tag-like badge comments to badges
// @version 0.24
// @match *://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/*
// @match *://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/*
// @match *://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/*
// @author The-Quill
// @downloadURL  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/The-Quill/badge-oneboxer/master/badge-oneboxer.user.js
// @updateURL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/The-Quill/badge-oneboxer/master/badge-oneboxer.user.js
// @grant GM_getResourceText
// @resource    badges  https://rawgit.com/The-Quill/badge-oneboxer/master/badges.json
// @run-at document-end
// ==/UserScript==

    'use strict';
    var Badges;
    $.get("https://rawgit.com/The-Quill/badge-oneboxer/master/badges.json", function(data){
        Badges = data;
    }).done(function(){
        var m = new MutationObserver(function(){
            ReplaceAll();
        });
        m.observe(document.getElementById("chat"), {childList: true});
        ReplaceAll();
    });
    function ReplaceAll(){
        var messages = document.getElementsByClassName('message');
        for (var i = 0, length = messages.length; i < length - 1; i++){
            ReplaceText(messages[i])
        }
    }
    var regex = /(\[badge:([a-zA-Z#.\-]+)\])/i;
    var ColourTransforms = {
        bronze: "CC9966",
        silver: "C5C5C5",
        gold: "FFCC00"
    };
    function ReplaceText(node){
        if (!node) return false;
        var badgeProperties = SelectBadgeProperties(node.innerText);
        if (!badgeProperties) { return false };
        if (badgeProperties.total == "") return false;
        node.innerHTML = node.innerHTML.replace(
            badgeProperties.total,
            "<span class=\"ob-post-tag\" style=\"background-color: #FFF; color: #000; border-color: #000; border-style: solid;\">" +
            "<svg version=\"1.1\" height=\"18\" width=\"15\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\"><circle fill=\"#" +
            (Badges.hasOwnProperty(badgeProperties.name) ? ColourTransforms[Badges[badgeProperties.name]] : "000") +
            "\" r=\"3\" cy=\"13.5\" cx=\"3\" /></svg>" +
            badgeProperties.name + "</span>"
        );
        if (HasBadgeText(node.innerText)){
            console.log("again");
            ReplaceText(node);
        }
    };
    function HasBadgeText(text){
        return regex.test(text);
    }
    function SelectBadgeProperties(text){
        if (!HasBadgeText(text)) return false;
        var matchesArray = text.match(regex);
        return {
            total: matchesArray[0],
            name:  matchesArray[2]
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

N.b. the current GitHub source already has some of these fixed.

Firstly, all lines are indented one level more than I would expect (the
first comment is also indented in the GitHub source); that seems to
break the user script annotation, as at the moment I don't see either
the description, the name, or the `@match` restrictions applied after
installation.

Otherwise formatting is fine, though the naming convention (upper camel
case for top level definitions) is unusual.  My editor also marks a few
lines with missing semicolon; that could be fixed just for consistency.

Even though it might not happen usually I'd ensure that all referenced
functions are defined before calling them, in this case `ReplaceAll` is
run from the callback, when it's only defined a few lines later.

The function `ReplaceAll` also returns `false` in a couple of cases, but
firstly, the return value isn't used anywhere and secondly, the function
doesn't return a value in one case.  I'd suggest to either always return
a value, or not at all.

The left over `console.log` should likely be deleted as it doesn't give
the reader much information.

In `SelectBadgeProperties` the regex match is done twice; it would make
more sense to only do the `match` and distinguish between the `null`
value and an actual match.

A minor gripe with `ColourTransforms` is that the starting `#` is left
out of the colour definition - this means that some external editors,
plugins, etc. won't recognize it as a colour.  I'd leave it in, in the
interest of compatibility and readability, even if it takes three
additional characters in the source.

And lastly, inserting many copies of the SVG image doesn't sound
performant, but I can't back that up with data obviously; I also doubt
that people will insert a massive number of badges and therefore this
point is kinda moot.

Otherwise looks great to complement the chat functionality.

Comment: The hash in Colour Transforms is already on the line above

Comment: I'm not saying it's missing entirely, I'm saying it should be put together with the actual colours so that tools can detect them as such.

Answer (score 2):

I apologize, but my review isn't going to be very vigorous.

---

### Don't check all elements

Every time a new chat message is added, you are searching through all the chat messages on the page for messages to one-box. This isn't very efficient; you've already one-boxed the passed messages, so you only need to handle the ones recently said.

You can do this using the `MutationObserver`. I can't get the docs up right now, but every time your listener function is called, some parameters are passed in that tell which elements have been, in your case, added.

Once you get those, pass them to the `ReplaceAll` function and have it only work on those elements. You could rewrite that function like this:

```
function ReplaceAll(messages){
    var messages = messages || document.getElementsByClassName('message');
    for (var i = 0, length = messages.length; i < length - 1; i++){
        ReplaceText(messages[i])
    }
}
```

This will allow for a list of elements to be checked to be passed in and, if they aren't, it will check all the elements.

As for when messages are edited, you may have to configure your `MutationObserver` a bit more (again, I don't have the docs up, so I don't know what you can do)

---

### `GM_getResourceText`

In your userscript metadata block, you are using this:

> ```
> // @resource    badges  https://rawgit.com/The-Quill/badge-oneboxer/master/badges.json
> ```

However, you don't use this resource later. Instead, you use jQuery to load the element asynchronously. Now, I'm not exactly sure how this function works, but you can much more easily get this resource just with `GM_getResourceText`:

```
var badges = GM_getResourceText("badges");
```

---

### Too much regex

I don't mean it as the header shows, but your `SelectBadgeProperties` function doing a lot with regex:

> ```
> function SelectBadgeProperties(text){
>     if (!HasBadgeText(text)) return false;   <---
>     var matchesArray = text.match(regex);    <---
>     return {
>         total: matchesArray[0],
>         name:  matchesArray[2]
>     };
> }
> ```

Right there, one after the other, you are matching a regex to a string. It would be simpler and faster to instead only use the match call:

```
function SelectBadgeProperties(text){
    if ( !(var matchesArray = text.match(regex)) ) return false;
    return {
        total: matchesArray[0],
        name:  matchesArray[2]
    };
}
```

---

### Misc

> ```
> function ReplaceAll(){
>     var messages = document.getElementsByClassName('message');
>     for (var i = 0, length = messages.length; i < length - 1; i++){
>         ReplaceText(messages[i])
>     }
> }
> ```

It might be better/faster if you instead check to see if the message actually has the badge text before you try to replace it. But, that's up to you.

---

> ```
> var m = new MutationObserver(function(){
>     ReplaceAll();
> });
> ```

can be simplified to

```
var m = new MutationObserver(ReplaceAll);
```

---

> ```
> function ReplaceAll(){
>     var messages = document.getElementsByClassName('message');
>     for (var i = 0, length = messages.length; i < length - 1; i++){
>         ReplaceText(messages[i])
>     }
> }
> ```

To me, it would make more sense to use `map` here because you are performing the same operation to each of the elements:

> ```
> function ReplaceAll(){
>     Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('message'), function(message) {
>         ReplaceText(message)
>     });
> }
> ```

---

Comment: In your last example, that wouldn't work because it's a HTMLNodeList not an array, and so it doesn't have the map prototype. You can fix this by putting that inside Array.prototype.slice.apply or Array.from

Comment: @Quill Gah, I feared that would be the case. Fixing now.